# App.config changed value is not picking up

Tags: winforms

I am using winform executable from release folder. when I am trying to change the value in the appName.exe.config it is not picking up. Instead its taking the old value that I used during compiling. Any thoughts ?

Comment: If your app is called foo.exe, then I'm assuming you are changing the contents of foo.exe.config, and not app.config, correct ?

Comment: You are right :). App.config is not part of release ( copy to local set to false )